# Azure web AD graph api with adal version 2 nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to pull azure ad user info using azure AD graph api. Will graph api work with adal 2 nuget packages?

Reason for this question is 
My webapplication is using below code in for auth and works only with Adal2x versions using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.

But Azure ad graph uses different way to pull token and it works only with adal3 .AcquireTokenSilentAsync is part of adal3.  AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode is part of adal2 for authentication on startup. I have to use both authentication and graph api. Is there any option to user graph api with adal2x version to match both?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        //If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            //AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            //code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

graph api code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            UserProfile profile;
            string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value;
            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            try
            {
                // Get the access token from the cache
                string userObjectID =
                    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
                        .Value;
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority,
                    new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential,
                    new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                // Call the Graph API manually and retrieve the user's profile.
                string requestUrl = String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    graphUserUrl,
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId));
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Return the user's profile in the view.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(responseString);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the call failed, then drop the current access token and show the user an error indicating they might need to sign-in again.
                    authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

                    profile = new UserProfile();
                    profile.DisplayName = " ";
                    profile.GivenName = " ";
                    profile.Surname = " ";
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "UnexpectedError";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
                {
                    //
                    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                    // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                    // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                    //
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                        .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                }

                //
                // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                //
                profile = new UserProfile();
                profile.DisplayName = " ";
                profile.GivenName = " ";
                profile.Surname = " ";
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
            }

            return View(profile);
        }
```

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the test, the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method is exited in version `2.28.3`. And in the latest version of ADAL(`3.13.8`), the method is support asynchronous. We can use `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` instead of `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`. To use this method, you can also refer the code sample [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs).

> But Azure ad graph uses different way to pull token and it works only with adal3 .AcquireTokenSilentAsync is part of adal3. AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode is part of adal2 for authentication on startup. I have to use both authentication and graph api. Is there any option to user graph api with adal2x version to match both?

Azure AD Graph is used to read and modify objects such as users, groups, and contacts in a tenant. It doesn't matther how we accquire the token to use this REST API.

And the [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) is helped to acquire the token from Azure AD, but the difference version has some difference. More details about the release version of ADAL, you can refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases).

In your scenario, both V2.0 and V3.0 version of ADAL should work. I suggest that you use the latest version since it fixed the several bugs in the old version.

Comment: Thanks I understood the background. Will token generated with the code from here work with graphapi? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662234/azure-ad-graph-api-not-pulling-user-information

Comment: I have replied the question, please feel free to let me know if you still  have the problem.

Comment: with this token, Can I get azure active directory group names using graph api? Do I need any specific permissions to access groups names? I am an azure portal contributor.

Comment: The Azure AD Graph REST validate the request based on the access_token. To ensure that you have the permission to read the group's , you need to ensure that there are `Group.Read.All` permission in the access_token. And you need to config this permission at the portal when you register the app. Please note, this permission is delegated permission. More detail about permission scopes about Azure AD Graph, please refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

Comment: Who can approve this delegated permission? Will this be portal admin or company it/respective department?

Comment: It requires the admin to give the consent to that app, after that everyone who can login-in this site could call the Azure AD Graph with this token. And if you register the app on the Azure portal, the permission already be granted by default.

Comment: I registered app in azure portal, but through graph api I can read user profile but not groups info.

Comment: Did you grant the `Group.Read.All` permission for that app? And are you able to check whether this permission is in the access_token by decoding it from [this site](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: I checked group permissions in ad permission s part in the portal. It prompted that it needs admin consent. I didn't tried to decode token but when I debugged I see a unauthorized 403 error at reading groups but not at reading user profile.